# Thread hangs during LDAP transactions

Tags: java, multithreading, openldap, rhel

I am facing a issue in production server. We are using Linux based server to connect to an External LDAP server. Problem is after some time when we try to query LDAP server from our Linux server it hangs and the GUI page does not show up anything. Here is the thread dump from the time when we see the problem.

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b19 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0xac926c00 nid=0x1229 waiting on condition [0x00000000..0xa6778ce8]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread-201" daemon prio=10 tid=0xa87e9800 nid=0xfbd runnable [0xa6962000..0xa6962f70]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
- locked <0xb980a7d0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:805)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"Thread-200" daemon prio=10 tid=0xa8f79c00 nid=0xfa0 runnable [0xa66e5000..0xa66e5ff0]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
- locked <0xb980d0f0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:805)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"Thread-199" daemon prio=10 tid=0xabe1d800 nid=0xf9f runnable [0xa689e000..0xa689ee70]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
- locked <0xb980f200> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:805)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"Thread-198" daemon prio=10 tid=0xa8f64000 nid=0xf9d runnable [0xa683c000..0xa683cef0]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
- locked <0xb9811310> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:805)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Can someone please suggest what is the root cause for this issue? And how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you setting any read timeouts?  And/or is it possible that the server doesn't respond?

Comment: no we have not set any read timeout, and we are still investigating on the root cause

Comment: facing similar issue, is it solved?